# How to turn a TYPE of Facebook notification back on again?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-notifications

I’ve used Facebook function to turn off certain types of notifications under the bell icon...

Basically you chose type of notification you don't want to see, click on the three dots and click "turn off notifications of this type" or "turn off these notifications" or whatever wording... You can only do this when the type of notification you don't want to see actually pops up as there's no real settings menu for it.

Works great, I don't see these types of notifications anymore but I accidentally chose one I really need to see... Specifically a notification for new pending post I need to approve in a group I manage. Sure, I can go there and constantly refresh to see if there's new pending post but it's way easier to just see the (1) displayed on the browser tab than just randomly check in all the time...

I went through all the settings, everything imaginable is toggled on, I tried through PC, tablet, and mobile phone but I still don't see that type of notification pop up under my bell icon.

Is there any way to revert that one I turned off accidentally? I'm really gutted as the only way to turn it off is under the bell icon and it looks like there's really no way to turn them back on anywhere else. And of course not even there as I don't see them anymore to click the three dots and change settings.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but believe I'm experiencing this exact problem now where I'm not getting comments when someone replies to my posts (or replies to my comments on someone else's post) unless they also tag me. That's true for my facebook friends and non-facebook friends. I'm replying in the hopes that you've been able to figure it out in the interim?